# Proving the arbitrary limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $x_{n}$ be a sequence. Suppose that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{2n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} x_{2n+1} = x.$$
Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n} = x.$

No clue how to start this, I'm looking into using the limit superior and inferior.

Comment: Maybe the $\epsilon$, $N$ definition might be useful here?

Comment: @RishiSonthalia what definition would that be? Please remind me

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x$ if for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that $n > N$ implies that $|x_n - x| < \epsilon$.

Comment: @RishiSonthalia oh the definition of convergence, yeah I don't know where that would come into play here

Comment: Rather than thinking about "where that would come into play", have you tried writing out what the definition would give you for each of the two given limits? Once you have done so, apply that definition to prove that limit for $x_n$.

Comment: @JJHoo oh okay I understand so I have to do something with epsilon here where I show that 2n and 2n+1 are less than epsilon so the limit is x? Does that sound correct?

Comment: One needs to be a bit careful and precise when working with mathematics. it is not $2n$ and $2n+1$ that are less than $\epsilon$ but rather a bit more. I encourage you to properly write out the definitions of $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_{2n}=x$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_{2n+1}=x$ properly, and work with the quantified variables given when proving the same for $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_{n}=x$

Comment: @JJHoo what are quantified variables?

Comment: Any variable must be quantified, with the quantifier either being the universal quantifier ($\forall$) or the existential quantifier ($\exists$)